# How to efficiently delete rows from a table based on text search?

Tags: mysql, left-join

An odd question to phrase, but slightly easier to explain in table structure. Two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `dictionary` (
  `id` bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term` varchar(255),
  `definition` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_term` (`term`)
);
```

The `posts` table contains large passages of arbitrary text. The `dictionary` table maintains a mapping of terms (that is, individual words that are likely to occur in text) and their definitions (a broader meaning).

Example of some `posts` data:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | text      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | foo       |
|  2 | bar       |
|  3 | foo bar   |
|  4 | foobarbaz |
+----+-----------+
```

Example of some `dictionary` data:

```
+----+------+--------------------------+
| id | term | definition               |
+----+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | foo  | A foo is a foo.          |
|  2 | bar  | A bar is a bar.          |
|  3 | baz  | A baz is something else. |
|  4 | quux | Who knows.               |
+----+------+--------------------------+
```

In the example data, there is an dictionary entry for the term `quux` that doesn't appear in the text of any posts. I'd like to delete such unused rows from the dictionary table, but due to the layout of the schema there doesn't seem to be a particularly efficient way of doing this.

The best I was able to cobble together is:

```
DELETE `dictionary` FROM `dictionary`
LEFT JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`text` LIKE CONCAT('%', `dictionary`.`term`, '%')
WHERE `posts`.`id` IS NULL;
```

... and it is sloooow. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to construct the `JOIN` condition, or a better way to do the `LIKE %...%`, or an entirely different approach to searching `posts.text` that will run faster.

(An aside, I recognize that having a many-many table that links `posts` to the relevant `dictionary` rows would be a much more performant way to maintain and search this data, but the application code is what it is.)

Comment: I wonder if `WHERE NOT EXISTS (check if posts table has the word)` would be any faster...

Answer (score 1):

Create table as select (CTAS) should work faster than delete with join.

1. Do `CTAS` using `where exists`:

CREATE TABLE `dictionary_new` AS 
select * from `dictionary`
  where exists(select 1 from `posts` where `posts`.`text` LIKE CONCAT('%',`dictionary`.`term`,'%') )

;

2. Drop original table

   drop table `dictionary`;
3. Rename table

   RENAME TABLE `dictionary_new` TO `dictionary`;

4.Create constraints

```
ALTER TABLE  `dictionary` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE  `dictionary` ADD UNIQUE KEY `ix_term` (`term`)
```